# NSPopover Background Color (Including Triangle) with macOS Mojave Dark Mode

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nspopover, macos-mojave

*Swift 4.2, Xcode 10, macOS 10.14*

I have created the following `NSView` subclass that I put on the root view of all my `NSPopover` instances in my storyboard. But I noticed that when I switch the color mode in macOS Mojave (from dark to light or the other way around) that it doesn't update the background color of my `NSPopover`.

```
class PopoverMain:NSView{
  override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
    guard let frameView = window?.contentView?.superview else { return }

    let backgroundView = NSView(frame: frameView.bounds)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor(color: Color(named: "MyColor")!)
    backgroundView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]

    frameView.addSubview(backgroundView, positioned: .below, relativeTo: frameView)
  }
}
```

I believe this is because a color mode transition only calls these methods ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface)) and **not** `viewDidMoveToWindow()`:

- `updateLayer()`
- `draw(_:)`
- `layout()`
- `updateConstraints()`

Has anyone figured out a reliable way to color the background of an `NSPopover` (including its triangle) and have it work seamlessly on macOS Mojave?

Answer (score 3):

It's funny how writing up your question leads to a solution (sometimes quickly). I realized I needed to create another `NSView` subclass responsible for generating the `NSView` that's loaded into the `NSPopover`. Note the addition of the `PopoverMainView` class:

```
class PopoverMain:NSView{
  override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
    guard let frameView = window?.contentView?.superview else { return }

    let backgroundView = PopoverMainView(frame: frameView.bounds)
    backgroundView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
    frameView.addSubview(backgroundView, positioned: .below, relativeTo: frameView)
  }
}

class PopoverMainView:NSView {
  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    Color(named: "MyColor")!.set()
    self.bounds.fill()
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it feasible to just extend `PopoverMain` `updateLayer()`'s method, and set `backgroundView.backgroundColor(color: Color(named: "MyColor")!)` inside as suggested in Apple Doc's source you linked?

Comment: how would you use this when the popover is declared in the appdelegate: let popover = NSPopover()?